# Updating WP plugin adds a user agent stylesheet, possible?

Tags: wordpress

Today I experience something very very strange. I updated a plugin in my WordPress backend, and my input fields changed in size!

Old situation:

[image]

New situation after updating plugin:

[image]

Now I see that after updating the plugin, the only difference in CSS is a important one, 'border-box', a user agent stylesheet:

[image]

But is it possible that a plugin-update causes a user agent stylesheet to be changed? I would say no, but after troubleshooting this came out to be the cause...

Comment: It's not causing the user agent stylesheet to change, it is just referring to it rather than the explicit statement it may have been before.

Comment: try in other browser and check the behavior. there might be some css change that is not reflecting fine in the browser

Comment: @VikingBlooded, can you explain that a little bit more? I did not change any of my LESS, it's just after the update this 'user agent stylesheet' suddenly is there causing problems.

Comment: One would assume that the update made a modification to existing styles that removed the governing style for this element and thus user-agent styles take over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user agent stylesheets are the browser defaults styles. When your plugin defines a style for `input:not()` before the update and didn't define this style after the update the browser default will be used.

The new version of your plugin don't create a new user agent stylesheet, but does not overwrite it as before.

User agent stylesheets plays an important role in cross-browser issues, that's why most people use a CSS reset, see: http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/